# useEffect is called twice with the same dependency value - dependency is observable mobx property

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, use-effect, mobx-react

I have react component that uses useEffect with dependency of mobx state:

```
useEffect((): (() => void) => {
  console.log(appState.getCurrent());
}, [appState.getCurrent()]);
```

relevant code in mobx state:

```
@observable private current = {} as any;

@action public setCurrent(c: any) {
  this.current = c;
}

@computed public getCurrent() {
  return this.current;
}
```

Very strange, but the useEffect is called twice with the same value.
Debugging setCurrent method, it's called only once.
more strange - I tried to change the dependency to appState.getCurrent().id, and it still got to the useEffect twice with the same value.
Can it be due to using mobx property as dependency of useEffect?
How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You must use with [autorun](https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html#useeffect) As shown in the documentation

```
useEffect((): (() => void) => {
  autorun(reaction)=>{
    console.log(appState.getCurrent());
  }
  
}, []);
```